# EADDRINUSE when using expressjs with node-webkit

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, node-webkit, nw.js

I want to use nw.js as a standalone socket client and server. I am trying to put the [sample](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) socket.io chat application from socket.io website into a nw.js application. But when I start nw.js I got the following error:

```
[5591:0222/143044:ERROR:nw_shell.cc(325)] Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:734:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:757:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1153:14)
    at listen (net.js:1179:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1266:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xxxx/nwjs/chat-example/index.js:23:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:451:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:469:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:346:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
```

**I have tried multiple ports and none worked.**
Here is the code I use for the server, which mostly the same as that provided by socket.io guide.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });


    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
});

http.listen( 3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Here is my package.json for nw.js

```
{
  "name": "socket-chat-example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "my first socket.io app",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.10.2",
    "socket.io": "^1.3.4"
  },
  "main": "index.html",
  "node-main": "index.js"
}
```

My nwjs version: **v0.12.0-alpha3-osx-x64**

Comment: You have some other application that listens port 3000

Comment: @AlexeyTen but I tried other ports randomly and none of them works ( e.g. 3001, 3023, 8883, 8000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [node-webkit-express](https://github.com/jaeh/node-webkit-express) for a working example.

I can't explain why, but launching express via "node-main" is what causes the issue. Perhaps it's a multi-process problem or something... but you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

The `node-main` script is run every time your application window is reloaded, refreshed or a new window opened.
Basically you want to start your server scripts as a `bg-script` instead. Here's the [manifest docs](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/Manifest%20Format/#bg-script). The background script is run once while the app running, so is the place where you should start your server.

You'll probably also want to listen to the nwjs window [close event](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/window#windowcloseforce) so that when the application is close you can properly shut down your server and clean things up.